# Finding all instances of length $N$ common subwords in two strings

Tags: string-manipulation

Given a pair of strings, I'd like to return a list of all common subwords of a fixed length of "n" characters (i.e. contiguous subwords of length "n" that occur in both strings), allowing for overlaps.  Is there a built-in or close-to-built-in way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Similar to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No intrinsic function to do that, but easy enough:

```
commonWords[string1_, string2_, length_] := 
 StringJoin /@ Intersection[Partition[Characters[string1], length, 1],
   Partition[Characters[string2], length, 1]]

stringA = "Thisisatest"
stringB = "Thisisanothertest"

commonWords[stringA, stringB, 3]

(*  {est,his,isa,isi,sis,tes,Thi}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** a simpler/faster alternative:

```
cmmnwrdsF2 = Intersection @@ 
    StringCases[{#1, #2}, Repeated[_, {#3}], Overlaps -> True] &
cmmnwrdsF2[stringA, stringB, 3]
(* {"est", "his", "isa", "isi", "sis", "tes", "Thi"} *)
```

---

**Original answer:**

```
cmmnwrdsF = DeleteDuplicates[
 Join @@ StringCases[(SequenceAlignment[#1, #2] /. {_, _} :> Sequence[]),
         Repeated[_, {#3}], Overlaps -> True]] &
stringA = "Thisisatest";
stringB = "Thisisanothertest";
cmmnwrdsF[stringA, stringB, 3]
(* {"Thi", "his", "isi", "sis", "isa", "tes", "est"}  *)
cmmnwrdsF[stringA, stringB, 4]
(* {"This", "hisi", "isis", "sisa", "test"} *)
```

Comment: Great, another method!  FYI for readers, $n = 3$ examples in this method and rasher's method match up (but are just out of order with respect to one-another).